# Como acceder a los botones estándar de un formulario realizado con QT Designer en PyQt6 con PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

Cuando se crea un formulario estándar con botones con Designer los incluye en una QDialogButtonBox. Para activar/desactivar los botones independientemente he llegado a la siguiente solución:

```
self.okb = self.btnBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Ok)
self.okb.setEnabled(False)
```

btnBox es como he llamado a la caja de botones.

Hay una forma menos retorcida?

Y ya puestos, como cambiar el texto que aparece en un botón creado de esta forma? La solución, con lo anterior es

```
self.okb.setText('Nuevo texto')
```

Pero la forma de obtener la referencia es lo que no termino de ver, si el botón tiene su nombre...

Answer (score 0):

No hay ninguna otra forma directa que sea mencionada en [la documentación](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialogButtonBox.html).

Por otro lado, leyendo dicha, cada botón es asociado a un rol, y no puede haber dos botones asociados a un mismo rol. Esto, me hace sospechar que en Qt (la implementación original) tampoco se almacenan por nombre.
En mi opinión, no hay por que preocuparse por que la forma mencionada en la pregunta sea retorcida, pero igual ofreceré alternativas.

Una vez aclarado que todo objeto de PySide deriva de QObject y pueden tener un nombre, debo decir que no se como funciona el designer... pero, si dicho le da un nombre o id unico al objeto de una forma similar al método [setObjectName](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.setObjectName), podrías usar el método [QObject.findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.findChildren) que busca todos los QObject de cierta clase y nombre que sean hijos de, en este caso, self.btnBox.

El siguiente código está sin probar.

```
self.btnBox.findChildren(QPushButton, "nombre_del_botón")[0]
```

Comment: Gracias Dante. Siendo las dos soluciones tal para cual, me quedo con la mía, me resulta más descriptivo el QDialogButtonBox.StandardButton.Ok que andar buscando el nombre del botón